# ALTER COLUMN TYPE smallint(5) to int(11) horrible slow?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, alter-table

I have a MySQL database (Innodb with ~5 Mio rows) and simply want to switch an unindexed value column from defined type

```
`USERID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
```

to be of type

```
`USERID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
```

So I simply need it to be able to store much bigger values (65535 is not enough). I tried using the update below, but it takes **17 Minutes** on 5 Million entries (SSD, 4 Cores):

```
ALTER TABLE tbllog MODIFY COLUMN `USERID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0';
```

I wonder why this takes so long and if there is a **simple but faster method?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution after some research and several tests. The fastest way is to first remove all indexes except the primary (takes only a second). Upon this, call the modification (took only 32 Seconds now!) and finally re-create the indexes. Re-creation of both indexes needed 1 Minute and 44 Seconds.

So finally I went from 17 Minutes to less than three Minutes.

Comment: So it was due to index recreation despite the altered column being unindexed? Interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yes, the affected column was not indexed but two other columns were. Looks like MySQL duplicated the table structure with the changed column type and then copied all line by line. So the indexes were slowing down all the process. If they're previously removed, this is not needed whily copying and the final re-creation is much faster.

Comment: Certainly, it makes sense once you think about it. In order to *enlarge* a column, MySQL most likely needs to recreate the complete table so it's able to allocate the extra space.

Comment: But the secondary indexes contain only the column(s) of the index plus the PK.  So, in theory, they don't need to be changed.  Sounds like this is an optimization they overlooked.  You could write a bug report at bugs.mysql.com